# Why does my SSIS job stop in the middle of execution

Tags: ssis

I just did a change in my job where originally the sequence of execution would be

step 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9

I need to add a check (Step 5)  and then depending if the value is true or false, it would go to step 6 or directly to 7.

Step 6 is unchanged.

The constraint is that if `@Variable1` is false, it goes to step 6. If the value of `@Variable1` is true, it'll go directly to Step 7. in this case, the value is false and goes to Step 6, executes and then ends the job successfully without error. Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constraints that lead to Step 7, specify that they use a "Logical OR".

Otherwise both constraints have to be true in order for the package to proceed.